# Jackson ObjectMapper - specify serialization order of object properties

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm implementing a RESTful web service where user has to send a signed verification token along with the request so that I could ensure that the request has not been tampered by a middle man. My current implementation is as follows.

Verification token is a VerifData object serialized into a String and then hashed and encrypted.

```
class VerifData {
    int prop1;
    int prop2;
}
```

In my service, I put data to be serialized into an instance of VerifData and then serialize it using Jackson ObjectMapper and passed along to the verification engine along with the verification token.

```
VerfiData verifData = new VerifData(12345, 67890);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String verifCodeGenerated = mapper.writeValueAsString(verifData);
```

But it seems that each time the application container is started, the order of properties being mapped into a string by ObjectMapper changes.

Ex: one time it would be

```
{"prop1":12345,"prop2":67890}
```

and another time it would be

```
{"prop2":67890,"prop1":12345}
```

So if client has serialized the VerifData instance as into the first String, there is 50% chance of it being failed even though it is correct.

Is there a way to get around this? Can I specify the order of properties to map by ObjectMapper (like in ascending order)? Or is there any other way to best implement this verification step. Both client and server implementations are developed by me. I use Java Security API for signing and verifying.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

From the [Jackson Annotations documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html):

```
// ensure that "id" and "name" are output before other properties
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "name" })

// order any properties that don't have explicit setting using alphabetic order
@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic=true)
```

Comment: from the link "all codehaus services have been terminated"

Comment: As mentioned below, if your goal is to apply the ordering everywhere rather than when serializing a specific object, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267506/2089674.

Comment: Why isn't there `@JsonPropertyOrder(leaveOrderOfPropertiesAsIs=true)`?

Answer (score 124):

The annotations are useful, but can be a pain to apply everywhere. You can configure your whole `ObjectMapper` to work this way with

Current Jackson versions:

`objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true)`

Older Jackson versions:

`objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);`

Comment: This is not quite correct (or at least doesn't work in all scenarios) -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267506/2089674 for a complete example of something that works.

Comment: @user2089674 - your example only works for Map keys. The OP requested a solution for Object fields.

Answer (score 24):

The following **2** ObjectMapper configuration are required:

`ObjectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true)`
or
`ObjectMapper.enable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY)`

> defines the property serialization order used for POJO fields 
>   **Note**: does **not** apply to `java.util.Map` serialization!

**and**

`ObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true)`
or
`ObjectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS)`

> Feature that determines whether `java.util.Map` entries are first sorted **by key** before serialization

---

Spring Boot config example (yaml):

```yaml
spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY: true
    serialization:
      ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS: true
```

Answer (score 12):

In Jackson 2.x, which you are probably using today, use:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
```

If you care about looks, you may also consider `SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT` as well.

Note that you must serialize *Maps* or *Objects* for this to sort correctly. If you serialize a `JsonNode` for example (from `readTree`), that won't be properly indented.

#### Example

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);

String input = "{\"hello\": {\"cruel\" : \"world\"} }";
Object pojo = mapper.readValue(input, Object.class);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(pojo));
```

results in:

```
{
  "hello" : {
    "cruel" : "world"
  }
}
```

Comment: There is only one map entry. I therefore cannot see it's order.

Answer (score 10):

In Spring Boot you can add this behaviour globally by adding the following to your `Application` entry point class:

```
  @Bean
  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {

    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.featuresToEnable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY);

    return builder;
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

There is an easier way in Spring Boot by specifying a property (in `application.properties` for example:

```
spring.jackson.mapper.sort_properties_alphabetically=true
```

Answer (score 4):

I discovered yet another way today in case alphabetic is not your desired sorting order. It turns out adding a @JsonProperty annotation on a field places it last when writing if the rest of the fields are not annotated. I discovered that when I wanted to specify a property name which did not conform to java naming conventions.

By Adding an index attribute you can define the order. Lowest index is placed first.

```
@JsonProperty(index=20)
String prop1;

@JsonProperty(index=10)
String prop2;
```

Would render:

```
{"prop2": "valueProp2", "prop1": "valueProp1"}
```

Answer (score 3):

From Duncan McGregor's answer:
Its better to use it like this:

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY, true);
```

as MapperFeature is for XMLs and comes with jackson-databind which is not required...

Answer (score 1):

You can use mix-in and specify the order of properties as you like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public final class ObjectMapperUtils {

    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    static {
        MAPPER.addMixIn(Object.class, IdFirst.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return MAPPER;
    }

    @JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "...", "..."})
    private abstract static class IdFirst {}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread, but since I was looking or an answer and landed here, some additional info could be handy for other people.
The @JsonProperty annotation I am using currently (jackson-annotations-2.11.2) accepts, besides the "value" argument, an "index" (numeric) argument that specifies the order of the fields during serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using flag argument:

```
objectMapper.enable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Gary Rowe mentioned, we can use Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder to sort the properties globally.
However for this to work, you must have Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder in your classpath. It is not part of the Jackson library.

As per [this documentation](https://tedblob.com/jackson-serialization-order/), spring-web dependency has Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder file and should be in your classpath.

```
@Bean
  public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {

    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    builder.featuresToEnable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY);

    return builder;
  }
```

You can refer to [this](https://tedblob.com/jackson-serialization-order/) for other possible solutions