# Spring REST @RequestBody validation in specific order and only one of group mandatory fields

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Lets say, I have below bean that I get in my Controller's entry method using `@RequestBody`

```
public class MyRequestBean extends RequestBean {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String lastName ;
    private String firstName ;
    private String ssnNumber;
    private String groupCd;

}
```

I have put `@Valid` at entry point method beside - `@RequestBody`.

I am trying to achieve two things,

1. `ssnNumber` is an absolute mandatory field - if its empty or null - no need to validate anything else. Just return the error message.
2. If `ssnNumber` is valid , see if any of the three fields - `firstName`, `lastName` and `groupCd` are valid with `@NotNull` & `@NotEmpty` . If any of the fields are present, handle the request.

How can I achieve this?

I am using these two dependencies for validation purpose ,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Validation API is - **1.1.0.Final** & Hibernate Validator is - **5.3.4.Final**

**EDIT:** Possible duplicate link is talking about JSON field order. In my case, field order doesn't matter. Its about field validation order. Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson ObjectMapper - specify serialization order of object properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577701/jackson-objectmapper-specify-serialization-order-of-object-properties)

Comment: Its not a duplicate, Hows JSON field order relevant to request bean validation? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found a way to do it with annotations i.e. order field validations with annotations.

I had to eventually write my custom validator class- `MyValidator` by implementing - `org.springframework.validation.Validator` and writing my ordered logic there and then adding that validator for that controller in controller class,

```
@InitBinder
    public void globalInitBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(new MyValidator());
    }
```