# Maintaining ordering of Class fields during Json Deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

Lets say I have a class as follows:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class MyClass {
   @JsonProperty(value="vertical") 
   private String vertical;

   private String groupId;

   @JsonProperty(value = "relationships")
   private void unwrapGroupId(Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>> relationships) {
    this.groupId =  ""; // Some logic to process the relationships map & set this.groupId based on the value set in this.vertical during deserialization

   }
}
```

When deserializing an API Response to MyClass, is it guaranteed that vertical field is set before unwrapGroupId() is processed???? Else my processing in unwrapGroupId() would fail as this.vertical will be empty. If not , how can it be achieved.

I looked up @JsonPropertyOrder, but looks like it doesnt solve this usecase

**Note: I use Jackson 2.8.1**

Comment: How look like your serializing process codes? Can you share it? Do yo call unwrapGroupId method before serialization?

Comment: @EmreSavcı I dont call it explicitly. The json field "relationships", is deserialized using the unwrapGroupId() method

Comment: But your method expects a parameter Map

Comment: "relationships" field in the json is basically a Map in the same format as the method param

Comment: Use @JsonCreator annotation on constructor. You can do your initialization there.