# XML fields custom sequence in Java Dto

Tags: java, xml

I am creating Java DTO from Xml string, But the sequence of fields are not the same.
For example Xml String:

```
<student>
            <name>Beff</name>
            <surname>Jezos</surname>
            <age>18</age>
</student>
```

Converted Dto is like:

```
<student>
            <surname>Jezos</surname>
            <age>18</age>
            <name>Beff</name>
</student>
```

Is there some annotation like this that lets us to put numbers of fields like:

```
public class Student {

   @XmlFieldSequence(place = 1)
   public String name;
   @XmlFieldSequence(place = 2)
   public String surName;
   @XmlFieldSequence(place = 3)
   public int age;

}
```

Comment: What XML (de)serializer are you using? If you're using the Jackson library then you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577701/jackson-objectmapper-specify-serialization-order-of-object-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this annotation from javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

```
@XmlType(propOrder = {"name","surname","age"})
    public class Student{
       public String name;
       public String surName;
       public int age;
    }
```