# Serialising order annotations for XML on Jackson does not work

Tags: java, xml, spring, serialization, jackson

I already googled this problem for almost a day and tried several fixes (including 4 or 5 from StackOverflow) but none of them worked. I have this POJO with annotations to work with Jackson 2.10.2

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "request")
public class PdfExportQuery {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "user", isAttribute = true)
  private String username;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "pwd", isAttribute = true)
  private String password;

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "putdoc")
  private XmlPutDoc putdoc;

  @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "import", isAttribute = true)
  private List<XmlPdfImport> imports;

  ... getters and setters
}
```

I use this POJO to create XML for some external requests. Everything works perfectly fine, but now I need to reorder the fields in the resulting XML and nothing seems to work.

I tried first setting it up at class level:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"putdoc"}) (Using only the field and localName)
or
@JsonPropertyOrder({"putdoc", "user", "pwd", "import"}) (Using all fields and localName)
or
@JsonPropertyOrder({"putdoc", "username", "password", "imports"}) (Using all fields and the java property name)
```

then I tried setting the order per field with:

```
@JsonProperty(1)
or
@JsonProperty(value="putdoc", index = 1)
```

I tried also setting JsonProperty on all the fields and only on the field I am interested to appear at first.

I also tried:

- Removing all the @JacksonXmlProperty and leaving only @JsonProperty on each field
- Combining @JsonPropertyOrder in the class and @JsonProperty on each field
- Checking that all annotations were imported from the com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation package

No matter what I do, the resulting XML always has the same ordering, all the ordering annotations seem to be ignored completely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson ObjectMapper - specify serialization order of object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577701/jackson-objectmapper-specify-serialization-order-of-object-properties)

Comment: No, i already tried that. I needed to implement a custom serializer just to get the order right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find a way to make it work with annotations. I needed to implement my custom serializer for the class just to change the order.